# How can I target Iframe on Firefox using HTML?

Tags: html, firefox, iframe

I'm a student developing a web site.

I placed some iframes in a WordPress page, and discovered that every link opens in new tab in Firefox.

The HTML code:

```
<a href="http://example" target="example">example</a>
<iframe id="example" name="example" src="http://example"></iframe>
```

I've looked up other similar questions and tried a few solutions (defining id and iframe name, not using capital letters in iframe name. I've also tried adding an at symbol `@` in the iframe name), but none of these work in Firefox. I've also checked PC Chrome, mobile Chrome, PC Edge, and iPhone Safari, no problems on these browsers.

I wonder, has anyone else experienced the same problem on Firefox especially, and whether someone can explain the reason?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. This looks like something is wrong with your particular install of Firefox. Maybe a browser extension is getting in the way. Or maybe you have some JS that in you didn't include in the question.

Comment: @quentin yes, my page has some scripts(p5.js) but the dylan's code is also opened in new tab. thank you for comment, I'm assuming the problem is with the wordpress editor. thank you for your comment.

Comment: My guess is you have a naming conflict in the page or maybe there is some hidden character in the id/name.

Answer (score -1):

I have a few theories.

1. Firefox doesn't fully support it
2. You forgot `.com` in your example domain.

Also, your code works for me in Chrome. Maybe it's a Firefox issue.

Comment: yes, the real codes are surely with .com. :) thanks for your time and confirming that this is firefix issue.

Comment: @soojoung Please consider marking my answer as correct, it helps devs like us a lot :)

Comment: The code works fine when I test it in Firefox. This isn't a Firefox problem.